# htaccess prohibits me from using full path

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, favicon

So i am just beginning to get my grasp around .htaccess and i have been able to prettify my URL's.

```
# localhost/index.php?side=kunder => localhost/kunder
RewriteRule ^([^\/\.]+)/?$ index.php?side=$1 [NC,L]

# localhost/index.php?side=kunde&id=1 => localhost/kunde/1
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)?/([^\/]*)?$ index.php?side=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

**Problem is** now i can't seem to navigate to my favicons which reside in root/favicons/favicon.ico

I guess it will treat is as follows: *index.php?side=favicons&id=favicon.ico*

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?side=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?side=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Don't really know what it means, but it works!! #MustBeMagic